# AttributeError: 'StructType' object has no attribute '_get_object_id' while writing parquet file

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, parquet

I am getting below error while writing parquet file in pyspark:

***AttributeError: 'StructType' object has no attribute '_get_object_id'***

Below is command that i am using:

```
df.write.format("parquet").option("schema",output_schema).save("test/parquet")
```

dataframe(df) has been created from reading csv file and has schema is as below:

```
StructType(List(StructField(ID,IntegerType,true),StructField(FIRST NAME,StringType,true)))
```

output schema is

```
StructType(List(StructField(ID,IntegerType,true),StructField(FIRST_NAME,StringType,true)))
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot specify the schema while writing the dataframe as parquet as parquet itself contains the schema information.

Just save the df directly and your schema will be maintained,

```
df.write.format("parquet").save("test/parquet")
```

Comment: Column name(FIRST NAME) of schema has space(" "), that is not allowed in parquet, yes i can rename that column in data frame but is there not any way to give complete schema again?

Comment: pass the schema to the dataframe before writing it. `df = spark.createDataFrame(df.rdd,schema=schema)`